# How do I find the Total number of disk blocks taken by the current directory (C UNIX)?

Tags: c, shell, unix, operating-system, stat

so I've almost finished my assignment where I basically recreated the UNIX ls -l command, but the only thing missing is the 'total #' that is shown at the beginning of the ls -l command as shown below.

```
total 68
```

From my understanding this is the total number of disk blocks taken by the directory. Is there a way to find this value from the stat function call itself? Additionally, I apologize if this may be a repeated question, but I couldn't find any resources that provided clear information. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have to compute this total (from individual file sizes). Use [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) combined with directory reads, e.g. [opendir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html), [readdir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html), `closedir` etc.

You could be interested by [nftw(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html).

> Is there a way to find this value from the stat function call itself?

No, because you need to cumulate the sizes.

BTW, consider also [du(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/du.1.html), at least for inspiration. On Linux, it is -like [ls(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html) is- [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software), part of [coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/coreutils.html). So you could study its source code (and/or use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to understand the [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) it is doing).

Look also into [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/439126/50557) answer to a related question. What I wrote there is useful to know for you.